# Is it possible to make my website to be viewed by particular country people?

Tags: web, adsense

I have created a website and also I got Google AdSense. Now I want my site to be viewed more by American People. Is it possible to track the visitors' country using the IP address? Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Have you tried using Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will return the users country and city in json format. Hope this helps.

http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=your-ip

If you want to get the latitude and longitude:

http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=your-ip&position=true